# How can I change 0123 into ACTG with tr or Perl?

Tags: perl, bash

I have a file with such list:

```
100
101
102
103
```

What I want to do is to replace every 0 into A, 1 into C, 2 into G, 3 into T.
Hence we hope to get

```
CAA
CAC
CAG
CAT
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be a code golf?  :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've practically worked out the answer yourself. Simply:

```
tr 0123 ACGT <input_file >output_file
```

or:

```
echo 2033010 | tr 0123 ACGT
```

Comment: Good call, +1, but I'm not sure the OP wants to be doing advanced DNA analysis in bash :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo the question title calls for a solution using "unix tr" among others.

Comment: @hobbs, I don't have a problem with the answer (I upvoted it) - I just don't usually think of UNIX text manipulation tools when genetic analysis comes to mind. I wonder how long the genome sequencing task would have taken if we'd done it with cmd.exe :-)

Comment: There's no analysis here. It's just changing the encoding from digits to letters.

Answer (score 7):

Here:

```
perl -p -e 'tr/0123/ACGT/'
```

Verification:

```
$ perl -p -e 'tr/0123/ACGT/' <~/input
CAA
CAC
CAG
CAT
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for completeness:

```
sed 'y/0123/ACGT/' file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo 3210 | tr 0123 ACGT
TGCA
```

When not using any options, `tr` takes two sets of characters, and makes a 1:1 mapping from the first set to the second set.  So, as written above, 0 maps to A, 1 maps to C, 2 maps to G, and 3 maps to T.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $ awk -vFS="" 'BEGIN{_["1"]="C";_["2"]="G";_["3"]="T";_["0"]="A"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf _[$i]}print ""}' file
    CAA
    CAC
    CAG
    CAT
```

Comment: Using `split()` makes the initialization neater `awk -F '' 'BEGIN {split("ACGT",a,"")} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf a[$i+1]}print ""}'`